# defaultValue not working React useForm hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, default-value, react-hook-form

default value not display on first render. Can you please tell me how can i display default values on first reload

```
<textarea
    cols="3"                                            
    name="businessDetail"
    defaultValue={businessDetail}
    ref={register({required:'required'})}
   />
```

```
  <Controller
     control={control} 
     name="businessTags" 
     as={<TagsInput />}
     defaultValue={businessTags} 
     rules={{required:'required' }} 
/>
```

```
<Controller
   as={<PhoneInput
   placeholder="+92 43 5673218"
   type="tel"  
    />}
   name="businessContact"
   control={control}
   defaultValue={businessContact}
   rules={{required:'required' }} 
   />
```

Comment: do you have a codesandbox?

Comment: perhaps you want to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHQC2NY0A-k